# Salesforce code limit

Tags: apex, managed-package, limits, package

We have a fairly large salesforce product with a large code base. We are going to hit the code limit of 3,000,000 very soon. I have read in forums that salesforce can increase the limit if we can justify the needed for increased limit.

But my question is that **will salesforce increase the limit for only the packaging org (created via the partner portal) which we use for packaging and uploading our package, or can we ask for increase in code limit for multiple orgs ?**

I am asking this because all our developers work in their separate orgs and checking in code in a common repository. From there the code is pulled into the main packaging org and finally the package is built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a custom template for creating your Dev orgs then salesforce will be able to increase the code size for you.

They are normal very good at this sort of thing as it reflects well for themselves to see it's APIS been used so much.

So in sort Yes they will be happy to do it (Normally) it might take 3-4 days to get it done. As for your Dev org's as i said if you have a way for Salesforce to know that these Dev orgs are from yourselves then they will be happy (We have custom templates that have higher limits then standard Dev orgs, code statements, custom labels, amount of classes such forth ).

If you do not have such a thing, Rise it with them and they will help you create them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim. We are not using custom templates for creating dev orgs. In this case if I first put a request to increase the limit in my environment hub org and then request to increase the limit in dev orgs created via the environment hub, then salesforce should not have a problem in  increasing the limit.

Comment: No worries. As i said speak to SF they will have a solution in place, You won't be the first nor the last person to hit this. But yes they will probably increase or Standard Dev org then roll out to a central org for you to clone